# How to generate aggregations like sum, average at row labels instead of column labels in excel pivot table using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am trying to produce an excel pivot table using apache-poi library.

[Base data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S630Y.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5p6I.png)

When i try to add multiple aggregations, excel was grouping it into **values**(you can see the values attribute in right side of 2nd image in row labels) and placing **values** in columns. I want to generate an excel with values in the row labels by default.

But when i add multiple aggregations like sum and average(as shown in the below image), the **values** are shown in column labels. **values** can be dragged to row labels in excel but i need the values in rows by default.

[But I am able to generate this in java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdSEQ.png)

Code for these aggregations

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

            //Create some data to build the pivot table on
            setCellData(sheet);
            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = null;
            try {
                pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference("A1:I8", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), new CellReference("M10"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("In sheet: " + ex);
            }
            //Configure the pivot table
            //Use first column as row label
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).addNewItems();
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).getItems().addNewItem()
                    .setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(1);
           //this.addCalculatedColumnToPivotTable(pivotTable, "field1", "average of count ab", "'count'");
            //Sum up the second column
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
            //Set the third column as filter
            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);
```

But there is no function in pivot table to add these aggregations in row labels in apache-poi library.

Comment: Show the whole code

Comment: Added the exact code

Comment: Going of from your pictures, it should be sufficient to call `pivotTable.addRowLabel(3);` as you want to have the values as row and not as column

Comment: I don't want values(i.e count values) to be in rows i want to get "sum of count" and "average of count" in row wise as shown in the 2nd image. If you see the column labels in the right side of the 3rd image. There is a attribute called values in column labels. That values should be in the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest  `apache poi` version `4.1.0` it is no more necessary to use the low level underlying beans for adding a column label since there is [XSSFPivotTable.addColLabel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPivotTable.html#addColLabel-int-) now.

But there is not any `addRowLabel(DataConsolidateFunction function, int columnIndex)` until now. The `addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction function, int columnIndex)` adds data on columns and data fields as col fields. So we need changing that if the need is having data on rows and data fields as row fields.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

class CreatePivotTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
   CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("M\\/d\\/yy"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

   String[] headers = new String[]{"Column1", "Column2", "Date", "Count"};
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   Cell cell;
   for (int c = 0; c < headers.length; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c); cell.setCellValue(headers[c]);
   }

   Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
    new Object[]{"A", "B", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1), 2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1), 4d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 1d},
    new Object[]{"A", "B", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 7d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1), 5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 1), 5d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 2d},
    new Object[]{"A", "C", new GregorianCalendar(2019, 0, 2), 8d}
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = sheet.createRow(r+1);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof GregorianCalendar) {
      cell.setCellValue((GregorianCalendar)rowData[c]);
      cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)rowData[c]);
     }
    }
   }

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).createPivotTable(new AreaReference("A1:D9", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), new CellReference("M10"));

   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

   pivotTable.addColLabel(2);

   // the default sets data on columns and data fields as col fields
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 3);

   // now changing from the default
   // set dataOnRows
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setDataOnRows(true);

   // add a new row field for data fields 
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getRowFields().addNewField().setX(-2);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getRowFields().setCount(3);

   // remove data fields from col fields
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().removeField(1);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().setCount(1);

   workbook.write(fileout);

  }

 }
}
```

The `x` attribute in a `field` element in either `rowFields` or `colFields` normally specifies the index to a `pivotField` item value. But `dataFields` might not be directly related to  `pivotField`s.

If there is only one `dataField` then there is only one possibility for showing that. So no `field` element is needed for that.

But if there are multiple `dataField`s, then there is a additional field named `Values` in pivot table's `GUI` view. In the pivot tables `XML` that additional field is indexed using `-2`.

So `dataOnRows` in `pivotTableDefinition` determines whether `dataField`s are shown on rows (`dataOnRows = "true"`) or on columns (default). And the `x` attribute `-2` in a `field` element in either `rowFields` or `colFields` specifies where the additional `Values` field is arranged in the list of fields.

Comment: Thanks Richter. You saved my day. It's woking

Comment: what does setX(-2) specify and what is it setting in this row ```pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getRowFields().addNewField().setX(-2);```

Comment: @Aravind Reddy P: The additional field named `Values` in pivot table's `GUI` view is indexed using `-2`. See my supplements.